# Create P4 branch but keep the history

Tags: perforce

I have a Product folder in perforce, which has bin, doc etc folder underneath it.

```
Product
    bin
      A.dll
    doc
      B.doc
    src
      C.cs
```

Now I want to add a layer

```
Product
    1.0.
      bin
       A.dll
      doc
       B.doc
      src
       C.cs
```

I want to keep all the file version info. I tried to branch or create a 1.0 folder to merge but neither way seems to be working. I would lose all the version history info. What will be the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `move`:

```
p4 move Product/... Product/1.0/...
```

Comment: you always get the versions starting from 1 when a name changes, but the history is still there

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the history without the indirection from moving, you can use a combination of 'p4 duplicate' and 'p4 obliterate'. 'p4 duplicate' does just that; it replicates the history precisely, but in a new path. You can then use 'p4 obliterate' to remove the original version.

Ganesh's solution is also great and 90% of the time that is what you should do, but if you are looking to do a deep rename to fix a structural problem, 'p4 duplicate' and 'p4 obliterate' are good tools to have in your bag.